# Zend 2.2, I'm building the form and input filters by factory, validation is occurring, but not being displayed?

Tags: php, zend-framework

The Zend quickstart guide:

http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html

Implies that the form factory can attach the filters automatically by adding them to the configuration array, rudimentary testing demonstrates that validation is occurring, but nothing is getting passed back to the view ( formElementErrors or formRow ).
)

Factory Array

```
$this->form = array(
            'hydrator' => 'Zend\Stdlib\Hydrator\ArraySerializable',
            'elements' => array(
                array(
                    'spec' => array(
                        'name' => 'name',
                        'options' => array(
                            'label' => 'Your name',
                        ),
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'type'  => 'text'
                        ),
                    )
                ),
                array(
                    'spec' => array(
                        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Email',
                        'name' => 'email',
                        'options' => array(
                            'label' => 'Your email address',
                        )
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'spec' => array(
                        'type' => 'Zend\Form\Element\Csrf',
                        'name' => 'security',
                    ),
                ),
                array(
                    'spec' => array(
                        'name' => 'send',
                        'attributes' => array(
                            'type'  => 'submit',
                            'value' => 'Submit',
                        ),
                    ),
                ),
            ),
            'input_filter' => array(
                'name' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters'  => array(
                        array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'),
                    ),

                ),
                'email' => array(
                    'required' => true,
                    'filters'  => array(
                        array('name' => 'Zend\Filter\StringTrim'),
                    ),
                    'validators' => array(
                        new Validator\EmailAddress(),
                    ),
                )
            )
        );
```

Controller

```
namespace Application\Controller;

use Zend\Mvc\Controller\AbstractActionController;
use Zend\View\Model\ViewModel;
use Zend\Form\Factory;

use Application\Form\Login;

class LoginController extends AbstractActionController
{
    public function indexAction()
    {
        $factory = new Factory();
        $login = new Login();

        $form = $factory->createForm($login->form);

        if ($this->getRequest()->isPost())
        { 
            $form->setData( $this->getRequest()->getPost() );

            /*
            if ($form->isValid()) 
            {
                die('valid');
            }
            else
            {
                die('invalid');
            }
            */

        }

        return(array('form' => $form));

    }

    public function loginAction()
    {

        die('login');

    }
}
```

View

```
<?php
    $form = $this -> form;
    $form -> prepare();
    $form -> setAttribute('method', 'post');
    $formLabel = $this -> plugin('formLabel');
    echo $this -> form() -> openTag($form);
    ?>

    <div class="form_element">
    <?php echo $this -> formRow($form -> get('name'));?>
    </div>

    <div class="form_element">
    <?php echo $this -> formRow($form -> get('email')); ?>
    </div>

    <?php echo $this->formElement($form -> get('security')); ?>

    <?php echo $this->formElement($form -> get('send')); ?>

    <?php echo $this->form()->closeTag(); ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From http://framework.zend.com/manual/2.2/en/modules/zend.form.quick-start.html

"*Validating forms requires three steps. First, the form must have an input filter attached. Second, you must inject the data to validate into the form. Third, you validate the form.* **If invalid, you can retrieve the error messages, if any.**"

I had wrongly assumed that the validation would automatically attach the feedback to the form. The code below attaches error messages if required.

Thanks to all SO users that took interest.

```
if ($form->isValid()) {

    $validatedData = $form->getData();

    // Do something useful

} else {

    $messages = $form->getMessages();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a quick one - I don't tend to use `$this->formRow()`, but I think you'll have add `<?php echo $this->formElementErrors($elementInstance); ?>`
into your markup